# diffrent declarations between sdk device query sample and occupancy calculator?

Tags: cuda

At the moment I try to get a better occupancy for my kernel and use the occupancy calculator and the device informations that I get from the sdk sample devicequery.
I'm wondering of a slightly different declaraion of blocks and streaming multiprocessor (sm).
In the sdk sample it's called

> total amount of shared memory per block

and

> total number of registers available per block

But in the occupancy calculator these informations are per sm, which makes more sense to me.

Is that only a wrong declaration in the sdk sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you.

Shared mem and registers are hardware resources, but block is a concept of the software programming model.

On the other hand, I think we can say that the max amount of the shared mem a block can use is equal to the total amount of the shared mem per multiprocessor of a GPU device.

The official doc CUDA programming guide also uses the term "shared memory per multiprocessor " as shown in the section [Compute Capabilities](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities);

Comment: Yes, in the case of shared memory I agree. But for the register count it's not possible. For compute architecture 2.1 1536 threads per block are possible and 63 register per thread. That would be 96768 register for a single block, but only 32768 register per block/sm are allowed. Generally I would say, too, it's all per multiprocesspr.

Comment: @hubs you won't be able to reach the maximum of both #threads/block and #register/thread at the same time during your programming design, since there is a hardware limit for max register/SM. You can also verify this inc the occ_calculator.xls

Comment: yes, that's the reason why I would say that it's all per sm and not block.

Comment: @hubs threads/MP is a hardware limit, for device 2.1, it is 1535. But max thread/block is a software concept, and it is still 1024 for kernel code runing on device 2.1